# What should I do with all this RAM?

Tags: asp.net, performance, visual-studio-2010, ram

The powers-that-be have decided to bestow memory upgrades on our developer team. We're all now in control of Mac Pro's with **32GB** of RAM. I would have preferred an SSD instead of half of that RAM and I'm struggling to think of ways to make the most of it all. To date I have installed the x64 version of Windows 7 and also set up a 4GB RAM drive for temp files, browser cache etc. as well as codefiles for the various apps I'm working on.

Despite this, even in the middle of a heavy-duty debug session with a massively multi-project solution I always seem to have what to me as obscene amounts of free memory left and I was wondering if there was anything else I could do to make the most of the available RAM. The only other thing I could think of was to run a virtual Windows server on my workstation for 'proper' (i.e. in a mirror of our production environment) local deployment/testing and so on, but any tools or tricks that could put the 4-6GB to good use in any developer or user-friendly ways would be very welcome.

I work with ASP.Net and SQL Server and use VS2010/12 so any 'tricks' specific for this set-up are especially welcome. I was saddened to see that all that RAM has not made VS2010 any less prone to fits of unresponsiveness.

Comment: You can buy 32 GB for less than $200.  It isn't worth as much as it used to be. ;)  The OS will disk cache as much as it can, so it's possible to use all the memory even if your applications do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas:

- use RAMdisk, and put your dev. environment on that... This will do wonders! Way quicker than the quickest SSD... But be careful, this is volatile! You could have 16GB, or even 24GB RAMdisk, and still have enough room to play with. Project switching has never been quicker, not to mention all disk based activities.
- you can run multiple virtual machines. Like if you use a DB for development, you could have a local copy, not having to rely on shared resources. This can  have a lot of benefits, though it has some drawbacks too (replication of changes by other developers, etc.)
- combine the above! Get a RAMdisk to run your VMs and the VS from that! This involves a lot of copying when starting work, but that is once/day... I think a coffee break, and reading through the emails would be enough. Benefits: quick... Quicker than anything - once it started.

Comment: Also make sure to use NTFS formatted ramdisk, FAT32 is much slower in real life.